# The transfer map from $K_2L$ to $K_2F$ for a galois extension $L/F$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-k-theory

In J. Tate's "Relations between $K_2$ and Galois Cohomology" Lemma 3.4 J. Tate talks about the transfer map in k-theory, and references the Milnor's "Introduction to Algebraic K-Theory", but in the proof of the mentioned lemma Tate uses a property of $K_2$-transfer 
$$f(\text{tr}(y))=\sum_{s\in G}sy$$ In the milnor's book there's not a proof of this fact, moreover, there's not a mention for the action of $G=\text{Gal}(L/F)$. Then, how acts G over $K_2$?, for the Matsumoto's Theorem, $K_2L$ has a presentation by the symbols $\{\alpha,\beta\}$ with $\alpha,\beta\in L^{\bullet}$. How acts $G$ over the symbols?.

Any hint for the proof of the formula above?

Thanks.

Comment: For the definition and properties of the transfer map for $K_2$ (called also trace), you should consult "A reciprocity law for K2-traces" ,
John Tate; Shmuel Rosset
Commentarii mathematici Helvetici (1983)
Volume: 58, page 38-47

Comment: Thanks for the response, i has read the article, the formula for $f(\text{tr}(y))$ above is used but is not proved, and the action is used over the cyclic algebras $\sigma(a,b)=(\sigma a,\sigma b)$, is possible that the action is the same for the symbol $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: So what prevents you to use the definition to derive the desired formula ? After all, the Milnor symbols are nothing but tensor products modulo relations, so the Galois action is deduced from the natural (diagonal) action on $\otimes$

Comment: Certainly, in the definition of transfer first define $f^{\#}:E(n,L) \to E(F)$ where $E(n,L)$ is the group generated by the elementary $n\times n$ matrices, and $E(F)$ is the direct limit of $E(n,F)$. Finally uses the schur multiplier $H_2(\cdot)$ (second group of homology) on $f^{\#}$ and takes direct limit... maybe i can use the homological transfer property, ill try it... thanks.

Comment: You could use the (co)homological transfer, but in view of Tate's goal (show the Licht.-Quillen conjecture for  $K_2$ of global fields), this would be tautological ! Of course, the L-Q. conjecture is now proved in general thanks to Voevodsky et.al.

Comment: I found a proof in here "https://www.math.nagoya-u.ac.jp/~larsh/teaching/F2005_917/norm.pdf" thanks...

Comment: Could'nt open the link